# How to sort output before writing to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sorting

I have a problem with sorting data. When I use the `json_dic.sort(key= lambda x: x['lastLogonTimestamp'], reverse= False)` command I get an error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'list'`. When I checked the output with the `type()` function, I found that I was getting the response in two classes, `<class 'list'>`  for objects that are empty `"lastLogonTimestamp": []` and `<class 'str'>` for those that have a value dates `"lastLogonTimestamp": "2021-02-15 06:35:34.363626+00:00"`

My input:

```
json_dic = [
    {
        "lastLogonTimestamp": [],
        "sAMAccountName": "batman"
    },
    {
        "lastLogonTimestamp": "2021-02-15 06:35:34.363626+00:00",
        "sAMAccountName": "superman"
    },
    {
        "lastLogonTimestamp": "2022-09-12 04:08:01.311201+00:00",
        "sAMAccountName": "green-lantern"
    },
    {
        "lastLogonTimestamp": "2022-09-13 04:48:43.275908+00:00",
        "sAMAccountName": "wonder-woman"
    },
    {
        "lastLogonTimestamp": [],
        "sAMAccountName": "hulk"
    }
]
```

EDIT: after following the advice I used this and it works fine

```
def lastLogonTimestamp_sort(value):
    timestamp = value['lastLogonTimestamp']
    is_str = isinstance(timestamp, str)
    return is_str, str(timestamp)

json_dic.sort(key=lastLogonTimestamp_sort, reverse=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the values returned by the `key` function have a uniform type. One option would be to convert to a string in all cases.

However, if you just transform the items into a string for the sort, you may end up with non-strings being sorted in between actual strings because of how they resolve with `str`.

To make sorting more predictable you can make a `key` function that returns a tuple of items to compare on, one per condition you want to check.

```
def timestamp_sort(value):
    timestamp = value['lastLogonTimestamp']
    is_str = isinstance(timestamp, str)
    return is_str, str(timestamp)


json_dic.sort(key=timestamp_sort, reverse=False)
print(json.dumps(json_dic, indent=2))
```

```
[
  {
    "lastLogonTimestamp": [],
    "sAMAccountName": "batman"
  },
  {
    "lastLogonTimestamp": [],
    "sAMAccountName": "hulk"
  },
  {
    "lastLogonTimestamp": "2021-02-15 06:35:34.363626+00:00",
    "sAMAccountName": "superman"
  },
  {
    "lastLogonTimestamp": "2022-09-12 04:08:01.311201+00:00",
    "sAMAccountName": "green-lantern"
  },
  {
    "lastLogonTimestamp": "2022-09-13 04:48:43.275908+00:00",
    "sAMAccountName": "wonder-woman"
  }
]
```

By changing `return is_str, str(timestamp)` to `return not is_str, str(timestamp)` you can now easily flip if non string values show up at the start or the back of the list, but never in between.

Comment: This only works if all times are in the same timezone. Otherwise you could have the situation where `2022-09-13 04:48:43.275908+00:00 will sort before 2022-09-13 04:48:43.275908+01:00 even though it is actually a later time`. See my answer...

Comment: @Nick Nice! +1 to your answer. This answer I'm focusing more on the issue of non-uniform types on the results returned from the `key` function. Absolutely agree that a full solution for OP needs to be timezone aware.

Comment: Yes - I've taken a more simplistic it's either a valid timestamp or it's invalid approach.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the sort key to a `str`. This will not modify the original type:

```
>>> json_dic.sort(key= lambda x: str(x['lastLogonTimestamp']))
>>> json_dic
[
  {
    "lastLogonTimestamp": "2021-02-15 06:35:34.363626+00:00",
    "sAMAccountName": "superman"
  },
  {
    "lastLogonTimestamp": "2022-09-12 04:08:01.311201+00:00",
    "sAMAccountName": "green-lantern"
  },
  {
    "lastLogonTimestamp": "2022-09-13 04:48:43.275908+00:00",
    "sAMAccountName": "wonder-woman"
  },
  {
    "lastLogonTimestamp": [],
    "sAMAccountName": "batman"
  },
  {
    "lastLogonTimestamp": [],
    "sAMAccountName": "hulk"
  }
]
```

If you want empty lists to come first, you could use:

```
>>> json_dic.sort(key= lambda x: x['lastLogonTimestamp'] or "")
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution. One thing to note for OP would be that non-strings could be sorted in-between real strings depending on how they resolve with `str`. e.g. `str([]) == str("[]")`. If that's an issue, then I posted an answer where you can sort based on multiple conditions to never allow that to happen.

Comment: @flakes True. We also don't know if the input data can have non-empty lists.

Comment: This only works if all times are in the same timezone. Otherwise you could have the situation where `2022-09-13 04:48:43.275908+00:00 will sort before 2022-09-13 04:48:43.275908+01:00 even though it is actually a later time`. See my answer...

Answer (score 2):

The issue with sorting timestamps as strings (as proposed in the other answers) is that `2022-09-13 04:48:43.275908+00:00` will sort before `2022-09-13 04:48:43.275908+01:00` even though it is actually a later time. It would be better to sort using `datetime` objects instead. For example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def ts(item):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(item['lastLogonTimestamp'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z').timestamp()
    except:
        return 0    # errors will sort first
        # return inf if you want errors to sort last instead'

sorted(json_dic, key=ts)
```

Output:

```
[
 {'lastLogonTimestamp': [], 'sAMAccountName': 'batman'},
 {'lastLogonTimestamp': [], 'sAMAccountName': 'hulk'},
 {'lastLogonTimestamp': '2021-02-15 06:35:34.363626+00:00', 'sAMAccountName': 'superman'},
 {'lastLogonTimestamp': '2022-09-12 04:08:01.311201+00:00', 'sAMAccountName': 'green-lantern'},
 {'lastLogonTimestamp': '2022-09-13 04:48:43.275908+00:00', 'sAMAccountName': 'wonder-woman'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When there's an empty list in the `lastLogonTimestamp` field, use an empty string as the key. Otherwise, use `lastLogonTimestamp`.

Using a helper function instead of a lambda function makes it easier to see what's happening.

```py
json_dic.sort(key=use_timestamp_key, reverse=False)

...

def use_timestamp_key(list_item):
    if isinstance(list_item["lastLogonTimestamp"], list):
        return ""
    return list_item["lastLogonTimestamp"]
```